# How can I create TensorProto for TensorFlow in Java?

Tags: java, tensorflow, protocol-buffers

Now we're using tensorflow/serving for inference. It exposes gRPC service and we can generate the Java classes from the proto file.

Now we can generate the `PreditionService` from https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/blob/master/tensorflow_serving/apis/prediction_service.proto but how can I construct the `TensorProto` objects from multiple dimention array.

We have some examples from Python ndarray and C++. It would be great if someone has tried in Java.

There's some work about running TensorFlow in Java. Here's the [blog](https://medium.com/google-cloud/how-to-invoke-a-trained-tensorflow-model-from-java-programs-27ed5f4f502d#.utw5gb708) but I'm not sure if it works or how we can use it without dependencies.

Comment: Thanks @mrry's suggestion and it works like a charm. I have the complete code to implement the tensorflow/serving gRPC Java client in https://github.com/tobegit3hub/deep_recommend_system/blob/master/grpc_service/java/src/main/java/com/tobe/GenericInferenceClient.java

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`TensorProto`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/framework/tensor.proto) supports two representations for the content of the tensor:

1. The various `repeated *_val` fields (such as `TensorProto.float_val`, `TensorProto.int_val`), which store the content as a linear array of primitive elements, in row-major order.
2. The `TensorProto.tensor_content` field, which stores the content as a single byte array, which corresponds to the result of [`tensorflow::Tensor::AsProtoTensorContent()`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/37256f4857cdadefa09e0505f4acc91ffbf626e2/tensorflow/core/framework/tensor.cc#L654). (In general, this representation corresponds to the in-memory representation of a `tensorflow::Tensor`, converted to a byte array, but the `DT_STRING` type is handled differently.)

It will probably be easier to generate `TensorProto` objects using the first format, although it is less efficient. Assuming you have a 2-D `float` array called `tensorData` in your Java program, you can use the following code as a starting point:

```
float[][] tensorData = ...;
TensorProto.Builder builder = TensorProto.newBuilder();

// Set the shape and dtype fields.
// ...

// Set the float_val field.
for (int i = 0; i < tensorData.length; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < tensorData[i].length; ++j) {
        builder.addFloatVal(tensorData[i][j]);
    }
}

TensorProto tensorProto = builder.build();
```

Comment: Thanks @mrry, can you provide the example to convert `TensorProto` to `float[][]`?

Comment: A little typo, I think it's `TensorProto.newBuilder()` instead of `TensorProto.Builder.newBuilder()`. Anyway, thanks for your help.

Comment: Fixed the typo, thanks for catching it. Converting the other way is trickier as you'll need to handle both the `float_val` and `tensor_content` cases (since you presumably don't control the producer). However, the principle is the same: read the linear array as row-major data and unpack into a multi-dimensional array.

Comment: Moreover, we need to set shape and dtype manually, otherwise the server may fail to parse TensorProto to tensor.