# How to use sagemaker java API to invoke a endpoint?

Tags: amazon-sagemaker

I was trying to run this example: [tensorflow_abalone_age_predictor_using_layers](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/master/sagemaker-python-sdk/tensorflow_abalone_age_predictor_using_layers/tensorflow_abalone_age_predictor_using_layers.ipynb)
, in which `abalone_predictor.predict(tensor_proto)` is used to call the endpoint and make the prediction. I was trying to use the java API `AmazonSageMakerRuntime` to achieve the same effect, but I don't know how to specify the `body` and `contentType` for the `InvokeEndPointRequest`. The document is not in detailed abou the format of the request. Greatly appreciate any piece of help!

Answer (score 3):

I have not tried the specific example but the below snippet should help you to invoke the endpoint for predictions

```
InvokeEndpointRequest invokeEndpointRequest = new InvokeEndpointRequest();
invokeEndpointRequest.setContentType("application/x-image");
ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.wrap(image);

invokeEndpointRequest.setBody(buf);
invokeEndpointRequest.setEndpointName(endpointName);
invokeEndpointRequest.setAccept("application/json");

AmazonSageMakerRuntime amazonSageMaker = AmazonSageMakerRuntimeClientBuilder.defaultClient();
InvokeEndpointResult invokeEndpointResult = amazonSageMaker.invokeEndpoint(invokeEndpointRequest);
```

I see the example you are trying creates a TensorProto and passes to the endpoint request. You can try to [create a TensorProto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39443019/how-can-i-create-tensorproto-for-tensorflow-in-java) of your invoke request and set as the body

Answer (score 0):

Just figured I can override the input_fn to convert the request body string to something can be fed to the model, in this case a TensorProto object.