# How to call sagemaker inference endpoint in Java ?

Tags: amazon-sagemaker

Is there anyone who has successfully implemented a sample code for calling an inference endpoint using sagemaker client java sdk ? I am trying to call a endpoint with text/csv payload.

Comment: Similar question for different payload, but might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51309523/how-to-use-sagemaker-java-api-to-invoke-a-endpoint

Answer (score 2):

+1 on leopd@.

A similar question: [How to use sagemaker java API to invoke a endpoint?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51309523/how-to-use-sagemaker-java-api-to-invoke-a-endpoint)

And Documentation for Java SDK: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/sagemakerruntime/model/InvokeEndpointRequest.html

Comment: Any Examples from AWS Labs ?